# Unable to pull the image from AWS ECR to my kubernetes cluster on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z237h.png)I have created a Kubernetes cluster using Kubeadm on AWS. I have private repository for my docker images on AWS called ECR. When I tried to pull this image from AWS ECR to my kubernetes cluster using kubectl run command.  It creates the deployment but in the pod It displays errImagePulling. I understand from  kubernetes documents that we don't need to create a secret policy while pulling image from AWS ECR as both cluster and image registry on the AWS itself. I attached my policy document also.  can someone please help me out?

Comment: Hi, can you put the source of this statement?

`I understand from kubernetes documents that we don't need to create a secret policy in while pulling image from AWS ECR as both cluster and image registry on the AWS itsel`

As without URL of Private registry and secrets, you can not pull images.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/  Please check in "Using AWS EC2 Container Registry"

Comment: It says that Kubelet needs extra permissions to do fetch the images from the private registry on AWS

Comment: I have created one role and attached these policies in order to pull my image.  ""{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
} """

Comment: Are you on a VPC that has internet access? The ECR endpoints are public and your master/nodes need outbound access to query the ECR APIs. I would also look at using the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` managed policy, rather than `*`.

Comment: I managed to pull this image using docker and ran the container also. It seems perfect from the AWS side as It worked for docker on the same instance. But in case of Kubernetes, It fails to pull the image and creating the pod.

Comment: Can you give the exact log message found in the kubernetes dashboard?